# Google Sheet: Identify if the specific ID has already been printed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm just wondering if there's a way for me to determine if data with a specific ID has already been printed. I'm collecting data with Google Forms. On Google Sheets, I have a separate sheet called "TEMPLATE" where I can view all of the data for a specific ID at once.

TEMPLATE:

[image: Template]

FORM RESPONSES:

[image: Responses]

For example, on the Form Reponses sheet, I want to print the data of  STUDENT ID: 4028451. So, after printing, I'd like the 'F2' cell to be updated with the letter "P." Is that even possible?

Here's the sample template: [SAMPLE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14J_VHfWfsmRQvuNVnG2YaN5w0vjHGKxt-6HcWUWNbgU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: About `So, after printing, I'd like the 'F2' cell to be updated with the letter "P."`, how are you doing this? It's a manual operation? Because, in the current stage, when the Spreadsheet is printing, there is no event trigger.

Comment: @Tanaike yeah, that's how I imagine how it can be done. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to do it automatically.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `However, I'm wondering if there is a way to do it automatically.`, unfortunately, I think that `So, after printing, I'd like the 'F2' cell to be updated with the letter "P."` cannot be achieved by a script, because, in the current stage, when the Spreadsheet is printing, there is no event trigger. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike oh okay. I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to programmatically modify the Sheet after an event, and that event is printing a sheet. You could develop an
[installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) based on events, but sadly there is no [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) for printing actions.